# How to find maximal value for "zfs set quota" without changing quota?

Tags: solaris, zfs

How do I find out how far I can go extending the quota on a ZFS file system (Solaris 10)? I was told to set `zfs set quota=none` and then set it back to the original value, but I'm not allowed to do it. Is there any other way to find out what is the upper bound on my storage system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The available storage space of the parent filesystem is a property you can read using `zfs get available <parent FS>`, but it would not impact the quota you can set in any way.

Quotas may be set arbitrarily high - the setting is not restricted by the quota setting of the ZFS filesystem parent or the size of the pool, it can exceed the available storage space by magnitudes easily.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, there is no parent FS, the file system I'm using is the top most one. "zfs get available" thus only returns the remaining free space (1TB actually; the storage should be ~40T). How do I find out the available storage space then?

Comment: @Pavel `zpool get capacity <poolname>`. Or just `zpool list`.